# Joining elements in list until certain element is found and skip it and add the rest

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list which contains data from certain logs where each line of the log is written as a new element and also a `\n (new line)` when it's completed and continues again.

My idea here is to add all the elements until \n is found in the list and add them to one string and send it to a different list and continue the process till the end.

Example:

> list1 = ['\tat ONEONEONEsun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native
>   Method)\n', '\tat
>       sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)\n', '\tat sun.nio.
>       ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)\n', '\tat sun.nio.ch.Se
>       lectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)\n', '\t- locked <0x0012550080d3
>       fe80> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)\n', '\t- locked <0x0445000
>       '\n', '\n', '\tat TWOTWOTWO.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)\
>       n', '\tat sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)\n', '\ta
>       t sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)\n',
>   '\tat sun
>       .nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)\n', '\t- locked <0x00
>       00000085d3fez0> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)\n', '\t- locked
>       <0x0000000080d40f80> , '\n']

I want to add the elements from

> `'\tat ONEONEONEsun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native
>   Method)\n', '\tat
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)\n',
>   '\tat sun.nio.
>   ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)\n', '\tat
>   sun.nio.ch.Se lectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)\n',
>   '\t- locked <0x0012550080d3 fe80> (a
>   io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)\n', '\t- locked
>   <0x0445000 '\n'

into one string and send it to another list, skip the `\n` element and again add it from the next element till the next `\n` is found and so on. Is it possible? I've tried the below way but the whole code is getting added.

I'm trying this to analyse certain logs that come to us and got stuck up here.

My code:

lines3 = []

> ```
> for x in range(0, len(lines1)):
>     if lines1[x] == "\n":
>         pass
>     else:
>         word = "".join(lines1)
>         lines3.append(word)
> ```

Sorry, the syntax above was not getting accepted as a code, hence updated as quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as "how can I separate my list-of-strings into a list-of-lists-of-strings, separating them based on the presence of a string composed of a single newline?".

You could use `groupby` to identify just-newline-strings and not-just-newline-strings, and append each group of not-just-newline-strings to a result list:

```
list1 = [
    "foo", 
    "bar",
    "\n",
    "baz",
    "qux"
]

import itertools
result = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(list1, key=lambda line: line=="\n"):
    #when k is true, v is a collection of newlines, which we don't care about.
    #so only append when k is false.
    if not k:
        result.append(list(v))

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux']]
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine `'foo', 'bar'` into one word and again `'baz', 'qux'` into another word, so we'll have 2 words in the list finally. e.g. `[foobar, bazqux]`

Comment: Replacing `result.append(list(v))` with `result.append("".join(v))` will give you `['foobar', 'bazqux']`. You could get `[foobar, bazqux]` without the quote marks if you additionally did `print("[" + ", ".join(result) + "]")`, but that's kind of silly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:
assuming `list1` contains your input data

```
temp = list()
list2 = list()
for line in list1:
    if line == '\n':
        list2.append(' '.join(temp))
        temp = list()
    else:
        temp.append(line)   # cache elements until '\n'
```

In a more fancy way you can use `itertools.groupby` to group elements around element `'\n'`:

```
from itertools import groupby

list2 = [''.join(group) for f, group in groupby(list1, lambda x: x == '\n') if not f]
```

If you print `list2` elements they should be same for both the above approaches.